# Makita impact screwdriver was dropped, now it doesn’t work. Prospects?

Tags: repair

I dropped a brand new impact screwdriver (Makita XDT 14) and now it won’t work. It’s like it’s has no power? I know it’s a good battery. The work light doesn’t work, nor do settings indicators.  Any chance of fixing it?

Comment: There's not much we can do with that information. There is no reset switch or anything like that. You can try another battery to make sure that's that battery you are using now. The instructions have a troubleshooting section, I suggest looking that over

Comment: So dropped it 5 feet or 50?

Comment: Guessing it was too much impact.

Answer (score 2):

If it's brand new, take it back to where you purchased it and get another one. Makita has great warranties on their products. Don't try to take it apart or otherwise fix it or you'll void the warranty. Good luck.

Comment: I agree that if under warranty and no visible damage I would take it back.